# Attribute filter Product Collection with other attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-collection

I have two Product attributes `prebook_date` and `release_date`
I want products with **prebook_date greater than today's date & prebook_date less than release_date value**.

I tried this code to get products which are presale_date greater than today_date

```
$today_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('prebook_date', array(
        'from' => $today_date,
        'date' => true,
        ));
```

Any suggestions how to **get products which have `prebook_date > today_date AND prebook_date < release_date`**

Comment: do you save prebook_date and release_date for a book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is little bit confuse. but try some thing greater than and less than like this

```
$today_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$release_date = "Your release Date";
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
'prebook_date' => array('gt' => $release_date),
'prebook_date' => array('lt' => $curDate)));
```

**UPDATE**

```
$today_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$release_date = "Your release Date";
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('prebook_date', array('gt' => $release_date));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('prebook_date', array('lt' => $curDate));
```

Comment: Thanks @mujahidh
In one line: I need products which have prebook_date > today_date AND prebook_date < release_date

Comment: try my updated answer